# Discord client status change w/ python

Tags: python, discord.py

I wanna create a python code, which changes MY custom activity (Not the one of some bot) to something random. I do not need help with getting something random etc, but by making a custom activity for myself. It seems like most ppl are only interrested in doing such thing for bots. I am a python newbie, so this question might be quite dumb (Most of my expirience is in C++, eventhough I have just started 2 months ago, so I am not very good there either). I would love to get some help on my problem of letting a python code change my own custom activity.
Thank you for your awnsers.

Comment: Checkout pypresence package.

Answer (score 2):

i reccomend going to the [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.self_bot) docs which has full documentation of what you're looking for if this is what you meant, to change your activity, you just put this..

```
await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="example"))
```

(you can also change the [activitytype](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.ActivityType) to something other than playing)

..into your bot on ready event, since you are saying you want it to change YOUR activity, itll be counted as self-botting, therefore your bot code will be looking something like this:

```
import discord
import asyncio
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=prefix, self_bot=True)

@bot.event  
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name=gamename))

bot.run('TOKEN', bot = False)
```

this will allow you to use bot "features" as a normal user account

self-botting is also against discord's tos, so be cautious of doing this.